# Facebook v3 sdk monodroid binding

Tags: c#, facebook, binding, xamarin.android, xamarin

Has anyone tried to create a new monodroid binding for version 3 of the Facebook sdk?  I've been using the older version of the Facebook sdk created with [Monodroid Facebook Binding](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/Facebook). But the new Facebook sdk has almost all of those methods as deprecated.

I'm having trouble setting up the new binding, basically the `com.facebook.android.Facebook` class is now deprecated and the `Facebook.Authorize` is replaced with `Session`.  I'm able to create a jar file of the new facebook sdk, but the `Session` class is not showing up in the object browser in visual studio when looking at the .dll.  The `Session` class is public and implements `java.io.Serializable` which is included in the `Mono.Android` reference.  Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

edit:
After messing around a few days with this I'm able to get past this issue with a work around that doesn't actually solve my problem, removing the node in `Metadata.xml`.

```
<remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.facebook']/class[@name='Session.OpenRequest']/method[@name='setPermissions']"/>
```

This brings about other problems, which can be solved by adding some more `<attr>` tags.

```
  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.facebook.model']/class[@name='PropertyName']"/>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.facebook.widget']/class[@name='GraphObjectAdapter']" name="visibility">public</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.facebook.widget']/class[@name='GraphObjectPagingLoader']" name="visibility">public</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.facebook.widget']/class[@name='FacebookFragment']" name="visibility">public</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.facebook.widget']/class[@name='SimpleGraphObjectCursor']" name="visibility">public</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.facebook.widget']/interface[@name='GraphObjectCursor']" name="visibility">public</attr>
```

After building this attempt I got to a point where I was getting multiple errors in the `GraphObject.SectionAndItem` class.

```
Error   41  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Com.Facebook.Widget.GraphObjectAdapter.SectionAndItem.Type' to 'System.IntPtr' E:\Android\FacebookBinding\FacebookBinding\FacebookBinding\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Facebook.Widget.GraphObjectAdapter.cs    345 64  FacebookBinding
Error   39  Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Com.Facebook.Widget.GraphObjectAdapter.SectionAndItem.Type' and 'System.Type'  E:\Android\FacebookBinding\FacebookBinding\FacebookBinding\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Facebook.Widget.GraphObjectAdapter.cs    344 9   FacebookBinding
Error   47  Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Com.Facebook.Widget.GraphObjectAdapter.SectionAndItem.Type' and 'System.Type'  E:\Android\FacebookBinding\FacebookBinding\FacebookBinding\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Facebook.Widget.GraphObjectAdapter.cs    381 9   FacebookBinding
Error   40  The best overloaded method match for 'Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CreateInstance(System.IntPtr, string, params Android.Runtime.JValue[])' has some invalid arguments E:\Android\FacebookBinding\FacebookBinding\FacebookBinding\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Facebook.Widget.GraphObjectAdapter.cs    345 17  FacebookBinding
```

To get around those issues I removed the nodes associated with these issues.

```
  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.facebook.widget']/class[@name='GraphObjectAdapter.SectionAndItem']"/>
  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.facebook.widget']/class[@name='GraphObjectAdapter.SectionAndItem.Type']"/>
```

Now the binding is able to be built successfully.  You'd think that I would be able to build and deploy my application now, another issue arises.  After adding the `.jar` file and the `.dll` file to my application I get these errors when building.

```
Error   62   package com.facebook.widget.GraphObjectAdapter does not exist
        com.facebook.widget.GraphObjectAdapter.DataNeededListener
    E:\Android\FacebookBinding\FacebookBinding\FacebookTest\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\com\facebook\widget\GraphObjectAdapter_DataNeededListenerImplementor.java    8   41  FacebookTest
Error   63   package com.facebook.widget.GraphObjectPagingLoader does not exist
        com.facebook.widget.GraphObjectPagingLoader.OnErrorListener
    E:\Android\FacebookBinding\FacebookBinding\FacebookTest\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\com\facebook\widget\GraphObjectPagingLoader_OnErrorListenerImplementor.java  8   46  FacebookTest
```

I'm at a loss now as how to proceed here. Any suggestions or comments to any of the steps to get to this spot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin is releasing a new version of `Mono for Android` 4.7.x that should be exposing some more java libraries that Facebook is using in their `.jar` file.  I switched to the beta channel and tried to compile this again and I'm able to use the `GraphObject`.  I think there is still some massaging to do with the `Metadata.xml` file to get the entire `.jar` bound, but this is a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using xamarin as IDE you can download directly the dll of facebook from the component site and avoid the problem of binding the sdk

http://components.xamarin.com/